# how to handle $rootScope in config of provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to handle $rootScope in provider method. I don't know how to inject it

```
 that.app.config ['$authProvider', ($authProvider) ->

    $authProvider.configure
      apiUrl: '/api/v1'
      handleTokenValidationResponse: (response) ->
        // How to handle $rootScope here?
        return response
  ]
```

Comment: That looks like coffeescript. You may want to add that as a tag.

Comment: you can't access rootScope at the config level, also `auth` looks like service not a config to me

Answer (score 1):

In the provider function, you cannot inject any service or factory. This can only be done at the "$get" method.

```
  this.$get = function($injector) {
    return function(exception,cause){
      var rScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      rScope.$broadcast('exception',exception, cause);  
    }
  };
```